# 2 masses, 3 spring system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, oscillators, normal-modes

I came across this problem in normal modes of oscillations.

> [image: 1]

Now I tried doing it this way:

The potential energy of the system should be $$ V=\frac{1}{2}K(x^2+y^2)+\frac{1}{2}K'(x-y)^2$$
and the Kinetic energy is, $T=\frac{1}{2}m(\dot x^2+\dot y^2)$

So in the matrix form, I can write this two as$$\left|\begin{pmatrix}
K+K' & -K'\\-K' & K+K'
\end{pmatrix}-w^2\begin{pmatrix}
m & 0\\0 & m
\end{pmatrix}\right|=0$$
$$=((K+K')-mw^2)^2-K'^2=0$$
$$=((K+K')-mw^2)=\pm K'$$
$$w^2=\frac{(K+K')\pm K'}{m}$$
Or $$w_1=\sqrt{\frac{K}{m}}$$
and $$w_2=\sqrt{\frac{K+2K'}{m}}$$
So the option should be D.

But the answer given is A.

If I am doing something wrong, please point it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last term of the potential energy should have the form
$$
U_{12} = \frac{K'}2 (\Delta l)^2, \quad \Delta l = \sqrt{(L+x)^2 + (L+y)^2} - L\sqrt{2}.
$$
For small displacements, $|x|, |y| \ll L$, we have
$$
U_{12} = \frac{K'}4 (x+y)^2 + \ldots
$$
Effectively, this change in the potential energy leads to change $K' \to K'/2$ in your formulas.

Comment: … not sure why this was downvotes… in any event maybe you can be explicit as to what is $L$.

Comment: I didn't down voted it. Btw thanx.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Users typically down vote "check my work" answers

Comment: @ZeroTheHero parameter $L$ is defined in the problem formulation. $L$, $L$ and $\sqrt{2} L$ are lengths of undeformed springs.